# Added row with JS does not align with th

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I am inserting a row in a table using a table template from the web (sorry if the prefix is long, but I wanted to include it). The problem is that the new `<td>` are not aligned with the `<th>` in the table head. I tried to insert `.text-center {text-align: center;}` or using `class="sorting text-center"` when defining `<th>` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921200/aligning-th-text-to-center-with-margin-auto-does-not-apply), but this did not solve the problem.

How can I align the new cells with the table heading?

```js
function addRow() {
  var tbodyEL = document.getElementById("employer_my_offers_body");
  tbodyEL.innerHTML += `<tr>
                                    <td> 12 </td>
                                    <td> 16 </td>
                                    <td> 50 </td>
                                    <td> received <td>
                                    <td> Later <td>
                                    <td> Empty </td>
                                <tr>`;
}


$(window).on("load resize ", function() {
  var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
  $('.tbl-header').css({
    'padding-right': scrollWidth
  });
}).resize();
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.tbl-header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.tbl-content {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

section {
  margin: 30px;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* follow me template */

.made-with-love {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
}

.made-with-love i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #F50057;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.made-with-love a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.made-with-love a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.top-buffer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  /*border-style: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            border-spacing: 10px;
            position: relative;*/
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" onclick="addRow()"> AddRow </button>


<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="max-height: 200px;">
      <div class="table-responsive col-md-12" style="max-height: 200px;">
        <div class="tbl-header">
          <table id="employer_my_offers_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <caption> Your offers </caption>
            <thead style="display:table-header-group">
              <tr>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Job ID</th>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Wage</th>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Effort</th>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Status</th>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Action</th>
                <th class="sorting text-center">Worker ID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl-content">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-height: 120px;">
            <tbody id="employer_my_offers_body">
              <!-- Offers will come in here -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How do you expect two separate tables to magically align their respective cells?

Comment: `<td> received <td>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: All you need is **one table**. Insert the new rows into the same table's TBODY and use [Table fixed header and scrollable body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body) as a solution to the sticky TH elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides your typos (unclosed `<td>` tags)...

- Use **only one** HTMLTableElement
- Never use inline `on*` handlers. Use JS's `.addEventListener()` or in your case jQuery's `.on()` method
- Don't import the jQuery library *twice*
- Use the jQuery `$()` generator to create new elements like your Rows
- Use `appendTo` to append an element into a target element
- Use `$("#someID")` instead of `document.getElementById` since you already use jQuery
- Use [Fixed table head - CSS-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923622/383904) as a solution for the desired sticky TH elements
- Improve the CSS

```js
const $tbody = $("#employer_my_offers_body");

const addRow = () => {
  const $row = $("<tr/>", {
    appendTo: $tbody,
    html: `<td>12</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>received</td>
      <td>Later</td>
      <td>Empty</td>`,
  });
};

$(".addRow").on("click", addRow);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-sticky {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.table-sticky th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #67d2bd;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button class="addRow" type="button">AddRow</button>

<div class="table-responsive table-sticky">
  <table>
    <caption>Your offers</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sorting">Job ID</th>
        <th class="sorting">Wage</th>
        <th class="sorting">Effort</th>
        <th class="sorting">Status</th>
        <th class="sorting">Action</th>
        <th class="sorting">Worker ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="employer_my_offers_body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing some closing `td`s in your JS innerHTML.

The problem was that the lack of closing tags resulted in generating 'filler' empty `td`s, resulting in ruining your layout even more. But the main problem is that you are inputting the new `tr` into the wrong place. Simply change `document.getElementById("employer_my_offers_tbody")` to `document.getElementById("employer_my_offers_table")` and you are good to go.

Note: you might need to play a bit with the styling (select each table rows you want to style with `nth-child()` for example, not all at once)

Comment: Thank you, closing the `td` helped but not fixed it. I guess the main error was to use two separate tables.

Comment: Yes, that is another thing. Try restructuring your HTML into one table, it will make the whole think easier to control